# HOWTO - trigger source button in ckeditor by another button which is outside the editor

Tags: ckeditor

I have a textarea which is behaving like a ckeditor.
In the editor there is a button to view the content as source/html.
I have a input button  above the textarea to preview the textarea content as html
Means on click of my preview button it will trigger the ckeditor button click.
Can anybody help me please..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shortest answer ever:

```
editor.execCommand( 'source' );
```

Comment: And this is [how to get editor instance](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-instances).

Comment: Hi , still not working
Below is my code

html
-------------
 <input type="button" id="btnPreviewHeader" value="Preview" onclick="ViewHtml();" />

 <textarea rows="30" cols="22" id="txtHeader" class="editor"></textarea>
-----------------------
javascript-

function ViewHtml() {
    $("#txtHeader").execCommand('source');
}

Could you please tell what am i missing..?

Comment: You call `execCommand` on a jQuery object. Not on `CKEditor.editor` instance.