# How to print preview in CKeditor 5?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have a document or html content I'm displaying on CKEditor. I want a print preview button on top of my document. I dug a lot into documentation but couldn't find the right api or plugin.

I found this pagebreak feature in which I can see "Open Print Preview" button which is exactly what I need, but I don't see an api or plugin information for it.
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/page-break.html

This answer tells me there's a native api for it, but can't find it anywhere. https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/5868#issuecomment-932193441

Do I need to do it manually outside of CKeditor using Javascript? Let me know.
I also tried this [CKEditor - Print Button Outside Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171272/ckeditor-print-button-outside-toolbar) but got an error saying function is not defined. I'm implementing it on Angular 9 currently.

I need to be able to go the browser's print preview window upon clicking a button from toolbar or somewhere on top of the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code for this solution on CKEditor [GitHub for pagebreak](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/blob/master/packages/ckeditor5-page-break/docs/_snippets/features/page-break.js)

Please remember to do the following to make it work similar to the page break demo page:

1. Include the following style to hide the print iframe container

   ```
       #print-data-container {
           position: absolute;
           width: 1px;
           height: 1px;
           margin: -1px;
           border: 0;
           padding: 0;
           white-space: nowrap;
           clip-path: inset(100%);
           clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
           overflow: hidden;
       }
   ```
2. Include an iFrame with id - print-data-container

   ```
   <button type="button" id="print-data-action">Open print preview</button>
   <iframe id="print-data-container" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"></iframe>
   ```
3. Include snippet.css file.

   < link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/snippets/features/page-break/snippet.css" type="text/css">
4. Include contents in page-break.js into a separate javascript file and import them into your HTML/JSP file. *(having it in the same file did not work for me because of conflicting end script tag)*